# Unknown column '' in 'where clause' c#

Tags: c#, sql, select

I try to do a Select with two conditions.
This is my function:

```
public static List<T> Select_mult(List<string> list, string op)
    {
        List<T> liste = new List<T>();
        using (MySqlConnection connexion = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=dev_ing2;User Id=root ;Password='';"))
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);
            connexion.Open();
            MySqlTransaction transaction = connexion.BeginTransaction();
            string req = "SELECT * FROM " + type.Name + " WHERE (";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in type.GetProperties())
            {
                if (p.Name == "Id")
                    break;                  
                foreach (string value in list)
                {
                    req += p.Name.ToLower() + " = ";
                    req += value + " OR ";
                }
                req = req.Substring(0, req.Length - 3);
                req += ")" + op +"(" ;
            }
            req = req.Substring(0, req.Length - 5);
            Console.WriteLine(req);
            Console.ReadLine();
            command.Connection = connexion;
            command.Transaction = transaction;
            command.CommandText = req;
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                T user = new T();
                foreach (PropertyInfo p in type.GetProperties())
                {
                    p.SetValue(user, reader[p.Name]);
                }
                liste.Add(user);
            }
        }
        return liste;
    }
}
```

I have an error Unknown column 'Chassot' in 'where clause'. "Chassot" is the lastName of a user in my sql table

Thanks to help. =)

Comment: check the values in your list?

Comment: Post what that `Console.WriteLine(req)` outputs

Comment: I suggest to use a fully tested ORM like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

Comment: is one of your properties in `type.properties` `"chassot"`?

Comment: Your syntax is off in the Where Clause.  Either than, or you're trying to reference a column that doesn't exist in that instance.

Answer (score 2):

If a column is of string type you should be enclosing values in quotes, which I don't see you do.

You should use one of the existing ORMs instead of trying to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance, it looks like this:

```
req += p.Name.ToLower() + " = ";
req += value + " OR ";
```

Should look like this:

```
req += p.Name.ToLower() + " = '";
req += value + "' OR ";
```

You're not wrapping your value in quotes. At least this seems to be the behavior that you expect. Please note that you may run into problems when you try to compare something other than a varchar.